# Unhandled Exception: gRPC Error in flutter

Tags: flutter, grpc

I try to use grpc in flutter, but I receive this error, when call some method.

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: gRPC Error (2, HTTP/2 error: Connection error: Connection is being forcefully terminated. (errorCod
e: 10))

Version:
grpc: ^2.1.3
protobuf: ^1.0.1
protoc_plugin: ^19.0.1

my code to init grpc:

```
class GrpcClientSingleton {
   late ClientChannel client;
   static final GrpcClientSingleton _singleton = new GrpcClientSingleton._internal();
   factory GrpcClientSingleton() => _singleton;
   GrpcClientSingleton._internal() {
   client = ClientChannel('localhost',
   port: 60051,
   options: ChannelOptions(
   credentials: ChannelCredentials.insecure(),
  ));
```

How can I fix that ?

Comment: Did you eventually figured out the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The reason I was facing this was that the server was operating under TLS, while I was passing `ChannelCredentials.insecure()`. Removing this line solved my problem.